# How to migrate an Android project to a cross platform project in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, cross-platform

I am new to Xamarin, and ios apps, and a bit less new (however far from veteran) to Android apps.

Therefore, I would like to start developing my app for Xamarin.Android using Xamarin (also, that's my only phone, and the only thing I can test for at the moment), and be able to migrate the app sometime in the future to Xamarin's cross platform development.

Is this possible?

How is migrating an android only app to cross platform done?

Thanks

Comment: If you made an application in Native Android and then wanted to move it over to Xamarin, you can do a couple of things: 1) Port over the Android app to `Xamarin.Android` which will be pretty much line for line Java -> C# or 2) Port over your application to `Xamarin.Forms` which provide a UI for Android/iOS/UWP/etc - https://www.xamarin.com/forms

Comment: @JonDouglas douglas I may have been unclear. the initial app is already in c#, but only for android, not cross platform. How to port to xamarin.forms from xamarin.android?

Comment: You can read how you would do that here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/introduction-to-xamarin-forms/ Unfortunately there's no magic bullet and you'll have to most likely re-code your existing application in Xamarin.Forms to leverage the library at it's fullest.